# In a Chrome Extension, detect tab already open and switch to it, otherwise, create new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In Manifest v3, I'm detecting a toolbar button click of my extension icon and opening a new tab from a page.html file in my extension folder. Trouble is, each time I click the extension's toolbar icon, it keeps opening this tab each time. How can I detect that it's already open and just switch to it, and, if not already open, create a new tab?

This is the service-worker code I have that is the problem. It needs a handler to detect that the tab might already be open and then make that already open tab as the active tab.

```javascript
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
  chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.runtime.getURL('page.html'), active: true });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution requires adding a Javascript Promise, a call to `chrome.tabs.get()`, and `chrome.tabs.highlight()`, using `chrome.storage` to store the `tab.id`, along with some error handling on `chrome.runtime.lastError` to your existing code.

```javascript
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    chrome.storage.local.get('UITabID',function(oSetting){
      resolve(oSetting.UITabID || 0);
    });
  })
  .then((nTabID) => {
    chrome.tabs.get(nTabID,function(tab){
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.runtime.getURL('page.html'), active: true },function(tab){
          chrome.storage.local.set({UITabID:tab.id});
        });
      } else {
        chrome.tabs.highlight({tabs:tab.index});
      }
    });
  });
});
```